# How do I update a tree branch in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

How do I update a sort_order field for EVERY child based on a parent ID in cakephp?

Comment: add some code otherwise I cant help you

Comment: What do you want?  It's a standard tree behavior in cake.  The code is what I need not what I have....

Comment: I mean what you tried ? please add  some query and input and expected output.